# Facebook wrong ID

Tags: facebook

[image: Why on Facebook different applications return different result?]

Why on Facebook different applications return different result?

Comment: Please test your applications, have you the same problem? Test old and new apps..
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Answer (score 3):

The answer is "App Scoped IDs", users have different (but unique) IDs in each App.

This may be interesting for you, if you want to identifiy users across different Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business/